# NativeScript: how to save and restore a page state?

Tags: nativescript

When we navigate to a page it reloads every time. If I previously created some views dynamically in it either programatically or using ui/builder all of this will be lost. Is there a way to save / cache the state of the page and restore it after the page reloading?

Answer (score 1):

Set a boolean variable when you have loaded a page. Whenever navigating back to that page, check the status of the boolean variable in the pageLoad/onNavigatedTo hooked up functions before the actual code in that page.

Comment: Well, I know how to check I'm back to the page. My question is how to save and restore the page state, when I previously dynamically added bunch of stuff to it.

Comment: oh! I am not quite sure about it, let me check, I will get back to you

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid of that there is no built-in feature for that.

What you can do is to store/reload manually your screen's data in [`application-settings`](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/modules/_application_settings_.html) at the `unloaded` and `navigatingTo` events.